# PHP Code for fetching one row in MSSQL in each registration process

Tags: php, mysql, sql, registration

Here is my query part of my registration PHP form.
columns `account`,`password`,`email` and `age` could be inserted by registration page user and they work well but, the column `account_id` needs to be increased by 1 automatically with each registration process.

Table name is `Account` not account and column name is `account_id`.

```
$query = "INSERT Account( account,password,email,pk_,type_ ) VALUES('$username','$converted_password','$email',1,'$age')";
$query_total = mssql_query("SELECT COUNT(account_id) FROM Account");
$results_check = mssql_query($query_check);
$results_total = mssql_fetch_row($query_total);
$result_total = $results_total['0'];
```

It gives me a NULL value for the (account_id) column and INSERT fails.

Comment: Why not set account_id to auto_increment?

Answer (score 1):

Perform the following query on your database: (Mysql based query!! not Mssql!!)

```
ALTER TABLE `Account` CHANGE `account_id` `account_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

this wil result in an autoincrement.
If this fails you'll probably already own duplicates, you'd have to solve this first. There are many ways for this, though it mostly depends upon connections with other tables.

After that for each insert into account do not include the account_id.
use the mysql query:

```
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

to retrieve the last inserted id.

within PHP you can use https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id though i'd highly advice you to start looking into http://www.php.net/PDO or http://www.php.net/mysqli with prepared statements.

Because as far as i've understood in the next version of PHP the basic Mysql functions will become deprecated. And prepared statements are better/safer. (If properly used)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am using MSSQL so i won't change to MySQL to make that step done.

Answer (score 0):

Set account_id to auto increment in MySQL and just don't shoot anything to the MySQL database for the field account_id. MySQL will automatically create a new ID.

Read something about auto increment:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

*edit:

Also change

```
$query = "INSERT Account( account,password,email,pk_,type_ ) VALUES('$username','$converted_password','$email',1,'$age')";
```

to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Account(account,password,email,pk_,type_) VALUES('$username','$converted_password','$email',1,'$age')";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I will not use MySQL anymore and my codes works well. I will try to find someway to solve NULL problem Thank you.